# Microsoft Word: Unspecified Error Location: Part: /word/document.xml, Line 0, Column 0

Tags: xml, ms-word

I've got a word document with the error listed above when I try to open it. I've tried several document recovery tools, but not had any luck. Other similar questions, (primarily with differences in line and column) number. 
I've unzipped and examined the file location pointed to, and tried notepad++ XML syntax checker along with other tools hoping to find a syntax error similar to what others have tried, but it appears that the syntax is fine.

The document was supposed to be a formula sheet for an exam, and has a lot of equations built using Words equation editor if that helps anyone. I would post the contents, but I think it may be too large. Here is the first line, which would contain the specified location if there is something obvious I'm missing (very rarely used xml).

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Anyone have ideas on what else I might try?

Comment: This is a general software question about an issue you're having with a Word document, not a programming question, and as such is more suited for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with "comments.xml". I found a post on extracting and inserting line breaks to the xml file; "Pretty print (XML only – with line breaks)" with notepad++.

https://bhrnjica.net/2014/01/23/how-to-manually-fix-content-error-in-microsoft-word/

But it did not help me - still showed the issue is on line number 0.

I extracted the xml file from an earlier version of the docx file, then compared the two comments.xml files.

After I while, I figured out that a bookmark start without bookmark end causes this issue.

I removed the bookmark start, injected the fixed comments.xml to the docx file. After that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and went trough the same hopeless struggle of trying to fix it. The solution I thought of in the end, and that worked for me, is uploading the file to Google Drive, opening it with Docs and from there, downloading it as a word file again. I'm not sure wether this will preserve your formulae, though, but you might give it a go. Hope I'm not too late with this reply for your exam!

Comment: Thanks! we actually ended up doing something similar. Opened with google dogs, then took screenshots of the relevant formulas so we wouldn't need to recreate all of them Not a solution per-se, but enough for our situation.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error from Word telling me my template was corrupt.  My solution was to first allow Word to repair the contents when I tried to open the template.  Word placed the repaired content in a new blank document.

Now, because the document is actually still corrupt -- I could never close and open the document without getting the same error message -- I do not save the repaired document.  Instead, I copy the content (except for the last paragraph marker) over to a new blank document.  That is the document that I save as a new template.  There is something about that last paragraph marker that holds a ton of information.  By not copying that marker, it gave me the text I needed minus the corrupt background data.

I did need to copy over some styles and rebuild some building blocks but that was minor work.

Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite dated, I know. Nevertheless it is still a top hit if you look for solutions to this specific error. So I ended up here and the hint about Notepad++ made me find a solution I wanted to share.

Playing with Notepad++'s three "Pretty print" options to no avail I also started combining them. And "Pretty print - indent attributes" and "Pretty print - indent only" successively did the trick. I found this not only does the obvious linefeeds and indentation but also removed whitespaces after '>'.

Because we had a ton of affected documents I wrote a PowerShell script that extracts document.xml, does a simple replace '> ' with '>' and puts the fixed document.xml back in the docx. The whole pretty formatting wasn't necessary to make it work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was **a subtle XML error** in the `word/document.xml` file inside `my.docx`.

I did the following to correct the error:

1. unzip `my.docx`
2. run `xmllint --format` on `xml/document.xml` and *replace* this file with the output
3. zip back and try to open with MS Word
4. it will show you the flawed line, i.e. the location of the error
5. correct the error in `xml/document.xml`
6. zip back and open with MS Word -- and voilà! :)

*Remarks:*

- The `.docx` format is in fact a `.zip`, so you have to unzip it to gain access to `word/document.xml`. After hacking with the xml files you have to zip the whole thing again to obtain a new version of `my.docx`.
- My exact error was this:
  "Microsoft Word: Unspecified Error Location: Part: /word/document.xml, **Line 2,** Column 0"
- Originally, the `word/document.xml` contains exactly two lines, the XML header in one line + the *whole content* in another. `xmllint` in step#2 above pretty prints the `.xml` file putting each XML tag into a separate line allowing to locate the error more easily.
- The concrete subtle XML error in my case (in step#4 above) was that the value of the attribute `w:hanging` of a `w:ind` tag *was in scientific notation (normal form)* instead of simple number in line 2400. It was `w:hanging="6.103515625E-4"` instead if `w:hanging="0.0006103515625"`. Hm..

My use case was this: I wanted to convert a LaTeX-created `.pdf` to `.docx`, so...

- I uploaded `my.pdf` to google drive and opened it in google docs.
- Then I downloaded it as `my.docx`.
- Opening the resulting file with MS Word throwed the error.

It is maybe the download function of google docs which put the error into the file.

Answer (score -1):

Try opening the document in LibreOffice, then saying back to Microsoft word.  I just had this happen to me, it worked.  The only thing LibreOffice didn't recover it the margin in the header.